# Adverb position in "Listen carefully to what I say"

Tags: adverbs, phrasal-verbs, adverb-position

I've come across the phrase "Listen carefully to what I say" and I'm really not sure why *carefully* has gone in between *listen* and *to*. It doesn't happen with other verbs; you don't "switch carefully on the light", for example.

When can an adverb follow a verb, and when can it not?

Comment: "Switch carefully on ..." is actually the unusual case - for most verbs it's completely natural to insert an adverb. I'd guess that it's unnatural because "switch on" is a bi-part verb. Compare it with "switch carefully on to the faster lane"

Comment: Because *listen to* is ***not*** a phrasal verb. It behaves like other non-phrasal verbs: *drive slowly in the snow, look closely at the picture*. If somebody has told you that *listen to* is a phrasal verb, they're using an unhelpful definition of a phrasal verb.

Comment: @Reionised: I'm afraid this has been flagged to close. I suspect it was due to your poor research. Please edit it to make it better. Remove your assertion that listen to is a phrasal verb. IMO, the question isn't half-bad.

Answer (score 9):

I think I've isolated the problem here.

Carefully (or some other adverb) sounds "natural" when it follows intransitive verbs, and "unnatural" when the verbs are transitive.

According to [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb):

> Some verbs allow for objects but do not always require one. In other words,  a verb may be used as intransitive in one sentence, and as transitive in another:

Compare:

- `I drink happily`
- `I drink happily to your health`
- But not `I drink happily the beer`. It's `I drink the beer happily`

JR's comment mentions `look carefully before...` sounding right and `place carefully the souffle` sounding wrong. The latter sounds wrong because it has a direct object.

Listen is always intransitive <sub>([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/listen))</sub>. So no worries there.

Also, the adverb can't split phrasal verbs, I think. `Listen to` isn't one <sub>(contrary to what you state in your question, see the Oxford definition above);</sub> `switch on` is <sub>([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/switch))</sub>.

You can say "Harry and Ginny gladly made out", or 'made out gladly'; but not "Harry and Ginny made gladly out"

**EDIT**: As Greg Lee points out in the comments, the `right` used informally in cases like `You're gonna fit right in` is  not an adverb, but a modifier for the preposition or the prepositional phrase, and doesn't violate this rule.

Comment: This is right.  Clausal adverbs (like this manner adverb "carefully") cannot intervene between verb and direct object.  This explains the unacceptability of "switch carefully on the light", since "the light" is the direct object of the particle verb "switch on".  (I know it's done, but I wouldn't call "switch on" a "phrasal verb".)  But are you sure an adverb can't come between verb and particle?

Comment: @GregLee: Can you think of an example where it does? I'm digging for proof as we speak.

Comment: "Stand carefully up", "sit carefully down"

Comment: @GregLee: `Stand up`, `sit down` aren't phrasal verbs. (But `stand down` is!). Anyway, I thought of one. See the edit.

Comment: "Right" in that example is not a clausal adverb, but rather a modifier of the following preposition or PP (cf. "fit right into the group", "the book stuck partly out of his knapsack").

Comment: @GregLee: Thanks. I'm on the right track, then. Yay!

Answer (score -1):

It's helpful if we look at this definition of **careful** from [Merriam](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/careful):

> a :  marked by attentive concern and solicitude

It might be stressing on the world "listen", so that the addressee will give his/her full attention to the addressor.

As for "switch carefully on the light", the more appropriate usage would probably be "*switch carefully on* the next lane" or if you wanted to go with the light, you can "*carefully switch on* the light".

Comment: I'm not seeing how the definition of _careful_ unwraps the mystery here, or explains why _Look carefully before you cross the street_ sounds natural and almost idiomatic, while _Place carefully the soufflé on the countertop_ sounds like it has a misplaced adverb that should be moved to the beginning or end, i.e.: _Carefully place the soufflé on the countertop,_ or: _Place the soufflé on the countertop carefully_.

Comment: @J.R.: I think I've solved the mystery. See my answer.